Rich text with image inside is not displaying in Lightning record page
I have rich text area on lightning record page with logo image. Image is stored in static resource as public.
This component is displaying in all lower env but not in production.
Verified in prod static resource is there and rich text area is there when we open the page in app builder.
Whole rich text area is not loading on record page. Please help!

            
                
                    decorate
                    true
                
                
                    richTextValue
                    <p><b style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 36px;"><img src="/resource/1713823758000/MyImage"></b></p>
                
                flexipage:richText
                flexipage_richText2
            
        
        

Try opening the image public url and see if the image loads. Is that used in salesforce org or community cloud?

Please check network tab, under chrome dev console once and see if static resource is loading properly.
